# ASP.net quick and dirty authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-authentication

I'm currently working on a page within one of my company's internet sites that is in response to some production issues we have.  The page will be published with the rest of the web site to our DMZ, however I'd like to set-up some quick authentication so only users on our domain (assuming they access the site internally) can access the page.  I'd like to use Windows authentication to do so.

Is there a quick way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to enable security just on one page in your application - not the entire app.

Under IIS, you can manage the security settings on a page by page basis. In the IIS manager, pick the page, and change the security settings so that anonymous is off, and only Windows auth is accepted.  You should get prompted for a login when you visit that page.

Answer (score 2):

#### From [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx)

> To enable Windows Authentication
>   within an ASP.NET Application, you
>   should make sure that you have
>   “Integrated Windows Authentication”
>   (formerly called NTLM authentication)
>   enabled within IIS for the application
>   you are building.    You should then
>   add a web.config file to the root
>   directory of your ASP.NET application
>   that contains an 
>   section which sets the mode to
>   “Windows”.
>
> You should also then add an
>    section to the same
>   web.config file that denies access to
>   “anonymous” users visiting the site. 
>   This will force ASP.NET to always
>   authenticate the incoming browser user
>   using Windows Authentication – and
>   ensure that from within code on the
>   server you can always access the
>   username and Windows group membership
>   of the incoming user.
>
> The below web.config file demonstrates
>   how to configure both steps described
>   above:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
         <authorization>
             <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

#### EDIT:

You can apply the auth settings to just a path in this way:

```
<location path="mypath.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="MyRole, AnotherRole" />
        <deny users="*" />
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Windows Authentication settings in IIS.  Just turn off Anonymous Access in IIS and set your NTFS permissions on the Web folder to the users whom you want to have access to the site.  Your IIS admin should be able to handle this quite easily.

Comment: Thanks.. if we turn off anonymous access though won't this protect the entire site?  I need the remainder of the site to remain public.. it is just this one page that needs to be protected.

Comment: You are correct, but you can adjust these settings on that specific page.  You _might_ need to put that page in a folder and change the settings on that folder; it's been a while since I've done it.